# write jpg php Arabic?

Tags: ar-php

I want to write on the picture in Arabic fonts
This is the code that I did, but I could not install the Arabic library correctly

```
<?php
 include('ar-php/src/Arabic.php');
 

if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
        $font = 'Almarai/Almarai-Bold.ttf';
        $font1= "Almarai/Almarai-Light.ttf";
        $im =imagecreatefromjpeg("certificate-1.jpg");
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $output =$name.".jpg";
        $msg="This Certificate is Auto Generated:". date("d/m/Y");
        $textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im,0,0,0);
        $Arabic = new Arabic('ArGlyphs');
        $text = '$name';
        $text = $Arabic->utf8Glyphs($text);



        // الصورة وحجمها وموقع الخط ونوع الخط ولونه والكتابة
        imagettftext($im,80, 0, 2000, 2000,$textColor, $font, ucwords($name));
        imagettftext($im, 30, 0, 10, 2400,$textColor, $font1, $msg);
        imagejpeg($im,$output);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/image');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($output).'"');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($output));
        readfile($output);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <title>
            موقع شهادات
        </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div  class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div  class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card" style="margin-top:20%">
                        <div class="card-header bg-success">
                            <h3 class="text-center text-white">
                                موقع شهادات تجريبي
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>الاسم:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" value="اطبع" name="sub" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to install the Arabic library, but the following error appears:

```
Warning: Undefined variable $Arabic in C:\xampp\htdocs\Certificate-Print\index.php on line 16

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function utf8Glyphs() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Certificate-Print\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Certificate-Print\index.php on line 16
```

I want to write on the picture in Arabic fonts
This is the code that I did, but I could not install the Arabic library correctly
I want to write on the picture in Arabic fonts
This is the code that I did, but I could not install the Arabic library correctly

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because **$Arabic** is null. I suspect that class name is not called **Arabic** ?

When I read the docs the class is called **I18N_Arabic**.  So your line should be

```php
$Arabic = new I18N_Arabic ('ArGlyphs');
```

You have too many things called Arabic for my liking - its a recipe for disaster.